# Why background video is not showing?

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm trying to include a video background in a HTML file but with no success. I'm trying to run it in Chrome or Safari, running in my machine locally, with no server. I don't know if it's relevant but I'm using Bootstrap 5.

Below I show de HTML

```
<div class="video-background">
    <div class="video-wrap">
        <div id="video">
            <video controls autoplay loop muted playsinline poster="picture.jpg">
                   <source src="videos/video.webm" type="video/webm">
                   <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below I show the CSS code I'm using:

```
<style>

video-wrap {
clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#video {
position: fixed;
display: block;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        transform: translateZ(0);
will-change: transform;
z-index: -1000;
}

video { 
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -100;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
background: url('') no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
transition: 1s opacity;
}

.video-background {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}
```

Does anyone know how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you found any errors in the console?

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://codepen.io/ryano-xmplify/pen/RwjjRMV
Check the paths to your video files. Check for any 404s.

Comment: Open the **console** in your browser's **Developer Tools** and check if there is an error mentioned (_eg:_ file not found? file is wrong format?)...